# Interesting tag cloud implementations

Tags: tag-cloud

What is the most interesting tag cloud implementation that you know? I'm searching for something easy to work with but somewhat non-standard. I know of [WP-Cumulus](http://www.codedifferent.com/2009/01/12/gorgeous-3d-tag-cloud-plugin-for-wordpress-wp-cumulus/) 3D tag cloud, I'm interested in an interesting implementation - not necessarily in visual terms (as an example, a semantic grouping tag cloud can also be interesting).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Form over Function disease!

The tag cloud concept is to show tags and their frequency, typically with proportional font size

The Cumulus 3D and similars are just special effects and do not show frequency very well, or at all!

Stick to the basics and your users will love you

Colour coding tags into groups is the simplest improvement without distorting the nominal function. Show the colour legend if possible

I personally also like colour intensity to indicate the recent usage of tags. A popular tag that has no recent posts will be in a large font size, but in a low colour intensity so that it fades away and looks less important. e.g.

[image: tag smaple]

Comment: Well, he says he is interested not only in the visual stuff (which is why I favourited and upvoted the question).

Comment: Thank you for the idea - it's a perfect example of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 9):

The most interesting tag clouds are probably those by Jeff Clark.

### [Shaped word clouds](http://www.neoformix.com/2009/AppleTwitterWordMap.html)

[image: Shaped word clouds]
<sub>(source: [neoformix.com](http://neoformix.com/Projects/portfolio/ShapedWordCloud.png))</sub>

### [Word Portraits](http://www.neoformix.com/2008/WordPictures.html)

[image: Word Portraits]
<sub>(source: [neoformix.com](http://neoformix.com/Projects/portfolio/WordPortraits.png))</sub>

### [Clustered word clouds](http://www.neoformix.com/2008/ClusteredWordClouds.html)

[image: Clustered word clouds]
<sub>(source: [neoformix.com](http://neoformix.com/Projects/portfolio/ClusteredWordClouds.png))</sub>

Comment: @anonymous, if you vote me down, please add why so I can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I don't like tag clouds. A sortable tag list make more sense, since you'll still get the same information, AND you'll be able to find anything you might be looking for. Preferably sortable by tag name as well as frequency.

Comment: A tag cloud delivers the same message as a sortable tag list, but has tremendously more impact because of its visual nature: one quick glance at a tag cloud and you know what's the site about. Combine this with a solution such as the one provided by user TFD in his answer and you can gain even more information from a quick look - no more sorting and reading, just visualizing.

Answer (score 0):

[Quintura](http://www.quintura.com/) search engine ([About](http://websearch.about.com/od/dailywebsearchtips/qt/dnt0830.htm)) is an interesting implementation of [tag cloud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_cloud)